# Best way to change font properties in lightswitch

Tags: silverlight-4.0, font-size, visual-studio-lightswitch, label

How can i change Label font properties (size, font and color) for any screen item i have ??

i found an extension that can give me some properties to play with (Pixata Custom Controls for lightswitch)

the problem with it is that i can change only data properties i cant play with the label style itself

for example if i have textbox screen item  lightswitch will generate a label and a text box for me  in the Pixata extension i can only manipulate the texbox but not the label

so what is the best way to manipulate font properties in general and label font properties in particular?

Comment: i did not pay attention to that, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from [BethMassi](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/beth%20massi/) in her [awesome blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/11/11/common-validation-rules-in-lightswitch-business-applications.aspx)  which was as follow

> You can select the style in the properties window for the control on the screen designer. Controls support basic Normal, Warning, Heading 1, etc. styles. If you want to change all colors, fonts, etc. then you need to create or download a theme. If you just want a single control to show in a different font/color then you can create a custom control.

thanks a lot beth 
Thanks Everyone :)
3oon